# Update api call in Redux

Tags: rest, redux

I've faced some simple problem when playing around with React and Redux. Consider this example. Let's say:

1) I have an app that renders article text and list of article tags.
2) App gets article object from api, saves it to redux store and pass it to the React component through props:

```js
{
  text: "lorem ipsum dolor ...",
  tags: ["lorem", "ipsum"]
}
```

3) User can add new tag to the list of tags (let's say through form).
4) To update database I need to dispatch action updateArticle(newArticle). This action makes put call to the server and return updated article.

My question is WHERE to add new tag to the array of tags before dispatching the action updateArticle? Inside component state or inside redux store ?

The obvious answer is to save array of tags in component state, add new tag there and dispatch

```js
updateArticle({
  text: this.props.text, 
  tags: this.state.tags
});
```

But in this case I'm managing data outside of Redux store, which as far as I understand doesn't correspond to Redux ideology.

Another answer is to add new tag inside Redux store through reducer, component props will be updated and then dispatch

```js
updateArticle({
  text: this.props.text,
  tags: this.props.tags
})
```

But this feels unnatural to change data on client and only then make api call which can fail.

So, what would your way to make UPDATE call to api? Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (async action creator) that will call the api and dispatch an action when the server responded and there was no error. This action should contain the information about the tag that has been added, and your reducer in the store should update the list of tags by adding the tag that comes with the action.

**Action (thunk)**

```
addTag = tag => dispatch => fetch(...)
  .then(result => dispatch({ type: 'tag-add', tag }));
```

**Reducer**

```
reducer = (state = {
  tags: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'tag-add':
      return { ...state, tags: [...state.tags, action.tag] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, tnx for reply. As I understand in your example we are pushing tag into array on the server. When request is successful we are pushing it in store. Right? So I need additional logic on the server? I mean for now I have one API endpoint /articles/:id to update whole article. So I need another one like /tags/:articleId to push tag into the database?